# Steps on howto install PySide on windows

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyside

I followed what they said at pyside.org but somehow i can't get it to work.
I downloaded the two files that they are linking from their site (qt libraries and pyside for python 2.6)

When I try one of their examples I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2dpainting.py", line 28, in <module>
    from PySide.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I use python 2.6.4 and windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the QT bin directory ("C:\Qt\4.6.3\bin") to your path environment variable.

Comment: Thanks! I added the directory you mentioned to the environment variable "Path".

Comment: You're welcome.  If it solved your problem, please except the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The situation with Windows binaries significantly improved in [1.0.0 release](http://www.pyside.org/2011/03/pyside-python-for-qt-1-0-released/). Try newer installers from [downloads page](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows).

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question on [Installing PySide - Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137847/installing-pyside-windows-8/35926556#35926556)

You can simple use

```
pip install PySide
```

to install it.